# How to downgrade from El Capitan to Snow Leopard?

Tags: imac, snow-leopard, install, startup, downgrade

I am not happy with El Capitan, and it is also not compatible with both music hardware and software that I have, so I want to go back to Snow Leopard on my late 2009 iMac.
After installing El Capitan the CD drive on my iMac is not working, and I was unable to install Snow Leopard from it.

So I made a bootable USB that gets recognized when I hold option when the machine is booting. When I choose it, I get the white screen with the Apple logo, but it doesn't go into the installation phase. I have formatted my drive and no longer have El Capitan on it.

How can I install Snow Leopard? It looks to me(and I'm hopefully wrong about this) like El Capitan has blocked the option to downgrade to an earlier OS, and it is a bit infuriating that I am not in control of hardware that I have spent a lot of money on.

Comment: Regardless of whether you have formatted the hard drive, you are able to boot to an installer with an earlier or later version of macOS. The question is whether the USB installer was created correctly as its obviously not functioning correctly. There are [steps here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/upgrading-your-mac-to-snow-leopard-using-your-usb-drive/).

Comment: It's also extremely unlikely that the CD drive was affected by the upgrade, it's just time that usually kills optical drives, lenses get dirty. When was the last time you tried to boot from it?

Comment: @tubedogg The USB drive works on other computers.

Comment: @tetsujin I installed Logic from a CD the day before upgrading to El Capitan and it was working perfectly then.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify a couple of your responses. 1. When you say the USB drive works on other computers, do you mean you're able to actually boot from it and see the installation options for Snow Leopard? 2. Re: the optical drive, @Tetsujin actually asked when was the last time you _booted_ from it?

Comment: @Monomeeth  1. Yes, 2. actually booted an install CD from the CD drive? I don't know, but I reinstalled SL before upgrading to Yosemite a couple of years ago, and then I was using the CD. I never had Lion, Mountain Lion or Mavericks, I upgraded directly to Yosemite.

Comment: I want to add that Lion installer works.

Comment: When you say the Lion installer works, do you mean using the optical drive or a USB drive? When you say you were unable to install Snow Leopard from the CD drive, what steps did you take? Holding down the C key during startup? Holding down the Option key during startup? Something else?

Comment: @Monomeeth El Capitan would just spit out the SL CD whether I was booting or the OS was booted. In Lion it accepts it when the OS is booted, but it spits it out during boot, if I hold alt or the C key. I was able to install Lion from the USB drive. I do not have the CD.

Comment: Ok, please answer the following: **1.** Do you have the 21.5" or 27" late-2009 iMac model. **2.** I'm confused - do you have a SL CD? **3.** If yes to 2, what happens if you power up the iMac, stick the SL CD into the Optical Drive so it is fully inserted, and then power off the iMac and power it up holding down the C key? **4.** As with 3, but holding down the Option key instead? **5.** Do you have access to other Macs and, if so, what models? **6.** Does holding down Command + R (or Option + Command + R) during startup do anything (I can't recall about that particular model).

Comment: @Monomeeth **1.** 27" **2.** Yes. **3.** The CD drive makes reading noises before spitting the CD out. **4.** I get the option to boot from the bootable USB or the HD. The CD drive makes reading noises and spits the CD out. **5.** Yes, I tried in an Apple store on a Macbook that came with Lion, but the CPU does not support SL so after booting from the USB I got kernel panic. **6.** It comes to the recovery partition of the latest OS installed. At first it was El Capitan, but after installing Lion it is the Lion recovery tool.

Comment: Is it a quad core model? And do you know _anyone_ who has a MacBook (any up to late 2009), either a MacBook Air or MacBook Pro (any up to mid 2009), a Mac mini (early 2006 to late 2009), Mac Pro (any to early 2009) or iMac (early 2006 up to late 2009)? If not, any other models?

Comment: @Monomeeth Yes, it is a quad core model, i5. And no, unfortunately I do not have any Mac that can run SL at hand. Right now I am trying to find a SL Time Machine image that I could get so I could try to restore machine from Time Machine backup, as that is the only thing I have not yet tried.

Comment: Okay, I think I have an explanation for you! There was a firmware update for the quad core models that resolved two issues, one if which related to higher than usual processor utilisation while playing audio through the headphone output socket. Because you're using music software/hardware it's almost certain you would have updated the firmware to fix this. Now, the thing about this firmware update is that it requires as a minimum Mac OS X 10.6.3 (so I'm guessing that's your problem - you're installer is for version 10.6.2 or earlier). You just need to get your hands on an earlier version.

Comment: Sorry-  I meant you need to get your hands on a later version!

Comment: @Monomeeth Wow, thank you very much for that information, you are an Apple god! The install disc that followed is indeed 10.6.2, however, the bootable USB has the 10a432 golden master build. Do you know which version that is? If it is indeed 10.6.2 or lower, I once again have a hope that I might be able to install SL :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am adding this as an 'answer' to provide more context as to what solved the OP's issue (and to save others from reading through the comments history). Hopefully this will help someone else in a similar situation.

In the OP's case he has a late 2009 iMac which previously had Snow Leopard (10.6.*x*) installed. He updated to El Capitan (10.11.*x*) and found this was incompatible with his music hardware and software. The OP then needed to go back to Snow Leopard and despite having both a Snow Leopard installation disc and a bootable USB installer, he was unable to install Snow Leopard.

The key bit of information that was missing in the original question was that the OP's iMac was one of the **quad core** models. These were options for the **27" model only** and both variants (i.e. the i5 and i7 versions) had a [firmware update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1031?locale=en_US). Because of the OP's music requirements I had no doubt he would have installed this update (and in fact Apple recommended that all users install it).

However, this prevented the OP from installing Snow Leopard because the firmware update itself requires as a minimum Snow Leopard (10.6.3). The installers the OP was trying to use were obviously for 10.6.2 or earlier.

**Summary**

**If you have a quad core i5 or i7 (late 2009) iMac and can't reinstall Snow Leopard, ensure that the version of Snow Leopard is either 10.6.3 or above.**

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Now on to fix the CD drive...

Answer (score 4):

As Monomeeth pointed out, a firmware update which requires 10.6.3 might have prevented me from installing from the CD and bootable USB.
I was able to get an image of 10.6.8 and restore it to my hard drive, and I am now finally running Snow Leopard!

Answer (score 2):

Solving a problem to install Final cut studio in Snow Leopard. I also had a BIG problem and hopefully this will help.

1. Partition your drive in El Capitan, find out how on YouTube.
2. Try to buy or find a Leopard install disk. El Capitan will read it OK.
3. Once you selected the partition where you want to install Leopard proceed to the installer.
4. Restart and again repeat selecting the same partition of Leopard, then you can install Snow Leopard and it will work.
5. Now with your drive having 2 partitions, when starting your computer simply press the <kbd>alt</kbd> (arrow) key and select either El Capitan or Snow Leopard to boot.

Hope this will help anyone facing the same problem I faced.